# Laravel - How to identify which model (out of two) via single html select option

Tags: php, laravel, html-select

I am listing Categories and Subcategories to the user in a select. If a category has subcategories, parent category is disabled to get selected. There are cases where category doesn't have any subcategories. So categories and subcategories are listed in same select.

On my controller side, I have two models (Category and Subcategory).  how could i determine the selection? (whether it's category or subcategory)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this few different ways.

For example give subcategories a value with `sub_category_` prefix and check in the controller if selected values has string `sub_category_` in it like following.

```
<option disabled>{{ $element->title }}</option>
@foreach($element->subcategories as $subcategory)
    <option value ="sub_category_{{$subcategory->id}}">- {{ $subcategory->title }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Or you could just have both `category` and `subcategory` in same table with extra flag named `parent_id`.

All parent category will have that value set to 0 and sub category will have the id of parent category in `parent_id` column.
You can then simply store the value without any extra work.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar. I added a second identifier to the value section like you did, then used explode() function in my controller to do the rest of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Set relation in model `App\Category` (assuming there is a model `App\Subcategory`)s:

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory', 'category_id','id');
}
```

Fetch categories with subcategories:

```
public function getCategories() {
    $elements = Category::with('subcategories')->get();

    return view('select', compact('elements'));
}
```

Generate select in view:

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect">
        @foreach($elements as $element)
            @if(count($element->subcategories) > 0)
                <option disabled>{{ $element->title }}</option>
                @foreach($element->subcategories as $subcategory)
                    <option>- {{ $subcategory->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <option>{{ $element->title }}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
...
```